# iOS APNS: Can two notification provider servers have same device token

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The apple documentation mentions there is no restriction on multiple provider notifications servers to send push notification to iOS devices.

Is it possible, the same device token can be used in two different provider servers deployed in 2 different network,to send push notifications to same app at any moment.

Will Apple APNS, allow 2 different provider servers, use same device key to send notification from each to same app in one device?

Comment: Yes, I've tried sending pushes to the same app from different sources and there was no problem with them being received.

Comment: But an app only has one device token per device, therefore  your question doesn't make sense - how could the two different sources have different device tokens? Where would they get these differing tokens from? (A device token can change but that is a very rare event, and if it does change then a push sent using the old one would not be sent regardless of the number of sources).

Comment: Hi Slutstokyovich, thanks for the quick response, true, no issues from different sources, but is it possible,2 different sources sending 2 notifications to same device using SAME DEVICE TOKEN and with same production certificate?

Comment: I give up. You're not listening. Look what my first comment said: "I've tried sending pushes to the same app from different sources and there was no problem with them being received." If they didn't have the SAME DEVICE TOKEN then they wouldn't have been received.

Comment: Hi Slutstokyovich, 2 different device token, I have no issues, my query is wrt  same device token in 2 different sources, having same production certificate, trying to send notification to same app, at the same time. Will one push notification be sent or 2?

Comment: ok, i got it bit late, sorry i took your time, Slutstokyovich, the issue is, we have 2 networks, each network has one notification source. Both the notification source have SAME device token and both are trying to send notification to same app at same moment. The app is receiving only one notification instead of 2. Both sources have same production certificate.

Comment: Have you verified that you can send a push successfully to the device from each network independently? i.e will the device receive two pushes if they are not sent at the same time?

Comment: Also if the device is offline when the pushes are sent then only one will be retained. From the push documentation: " If multiple notifications are sent while the device is offline, each new notification causes the prior notification to be discarded. This behavior of keeping only the newest notification is referred to as coalescing notifications."

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes, both are able to send notifications, without any exceptions. I have checked the logs in both the environments, both the environment logs say, push notification successful, but only one notification is received.  If they are not sent at same time also, only one notification is received. This problem is very weird, since both the sources have same production certificate, both says notification sent, but app receives only one notification. The difference is, sources are in 2 different networks. I am not able to figure out the cause why APNS reacts differently?

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. My question was can you send a push from one source and it is received on the device, then switch to another source and send a push and it is received on the device.

Comment: I unit tested notifications from both network one after another not multiple, from one network its a success and from other network a failure, app being in online mode.

Comment: Then you ought to double check that the device token and environment and profiles you are using for the network that does't work are all correct. If you've never been able to send a push from that network how do you know for certain its configured correctly.

Comment: slutstokyovich, yes, i have tried the scenario you suggested, but only one notification is received. I dont know why from other network, logs says notification success without any error, but app doesnt receive notification.

Comment: If a push is sent out but never received the most likely cause is the token is incorrect. If you use the dev token with a prod environment or vice versa it won't be received. Are you 100% sure the device token is correct for both sources and everything else about them is absolutely identical.

Comment: slutstokyovich, you are making a write statement, is server configured properly. The notification did not work on the first go, server raised connection refused to "gateway.push.apple.com" at port 2195, due to firewall. We enabled both. Then again tried sending notification after firewall change, this time, connections worked, notification sent from server(from server logs) but client app doesnt receive notifications.

Comment: This is the setup, I have IPhone 5s, with the app, 2 sources with same production certificate, but sources are in different network. Sure device token is same for both, i have matched the logs again and again.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the device token is the same for both sources? The problem doesn't sound anything to do with two sources both sending to the same device, one source just isn't working.

Comment: yes, device token is same, 100% sure. That's the reason for frustration. All are identical except the network. That's why i am get doubt towards network. What else in the network i have to fix? apple documentation doesnt mention on this.

Comment: slutstokyovich, let me try to give you more details,                                Have below setup
1. One App
2.Two different networks, consider NW1 and NW2 having one instance of provider server each.
3.Both provider server have identical production certificate.
4.Same device token "123-456"

Comment: I tried below steps, to send 2 notifications to app from both the networks,
1.The app is connected to NW1 via APNS.
2.The app is not connected to NW2 via APNS.
3.I tried sending notification to app from NW1 with device token "123-456", notification is successfully sent.The device is getting the notification to the app.
4.I tried sending notification to app from NW2 with same device token "123-456", notification is sent from server successfully. But the device is not getting the notification.

Comment: What could be the reason, ideally device should receive both the notification's from both the networks, but device is receiving only 1 notification and from one network only always. Can it be due to APNS is not aware of NW2, the notifications are not sent?

Comment: Hi Slutstokyovich, the issue is resolved. The problem was in one of the environment the server code still pointing to dev sandbox. This is due to failure in build and deployment in one environment. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can have multiple Gateways (SNS, Urban Airship, PushIO, etc.) connected to one platform provider (APNS, GCM, Amazon, etc.), the most important thing is the token/registration ID (specific to a device and an Application) and the certificate if you are using APNS.

Many people ask how the feedback sent by the platform provider is handled in this case.

Since feedback is **idempotent**, it should work without problem for different gateways; tokens saved on each Gateway can be handled in the backend application. If for example APNS sends a feedback to SNS saying that an endpoint is no longer valid (maybe because the user has uninstalled the Application), the token can directly be updated/removed from all the other Gateways. You can also leave it as it is and wait for the feedback sent by APNS to other gateways when they send notifications to the endpoint, and then update your endpoints list accordingly in those gateways.
The most important thing to note here is that feedback is idempotent, if SNS sends a push notification to an endpoint and receive a feedback, another gateway that sends a push notification to the same token will receive the same feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This is my experience while working with APNS, this is like a checklist, before you start testing notification in any environment,

1. Certificates will decide server can connect to APN or not.
2. According to the certificate you have for ex. dev certificate or production
   certificate, point to respective APNS sandbox.

   > Production Sandbox:-
   >        Hostname: gateway.push.apple.com ,
   >        Port: 2195
   >
   > Development environment:- 
   >        Hostname: gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com ,
   >        Port: 2195
3. There is no restriction that production certificate can be used in only one server or in only one network. The same production certificate can be used in multiple boxes or multiple networks to send notification to same app on a device.
4. Most important is checking Firewall is blocking connectivity from your network to APNS Dev or Production. So do a telnet to both production and dev environment APNS. The connection should not be blocked.
5. If firewall is blocking connectivity to APNS, the server code will throw "Connection Refused" or "Connection Closed" exception while sending push notification.
6. This is the most weird behavior I saw with APNS and certificate, because of which I lost 2-3 days. I experienced below depending upon the case,

   - Server is pointing to APNS Dev environment, certificate is
     "Production", while sending notification to APNS, **SOMETIMES**
     server will throw "Socket Closed Exception".
   - Server is pointing to APNS Dev environment, certificate is "Production", while sending notification to APNS, server logs says
     notification sent to APNS, but device will not receive the
     notification.

:) If you have done wrong configurations, you should be lucky to get "Socket Closed Exception".

If all the configurations are correct(for ex credentials, firewall), correct certificate and pointing to right APNS environment, the device will defiantly get a push notification. Push notification will work like a charm. It will be instant .

Hope this checklist will help in your implementation and sanity checks.